# Does $B/A \cong D/C$ imply $C/A \cong D/B$ for fin. gen. free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Let $A,B,C,D$ be finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, s.t. $A \subseteq B,C$ and $B,C \subseteq D$. Moreover, all quotients should be finite abelian groups and $B/A \cong D/C$. Does this imply $C/A \cong D/B$?

Comment: When you write that $B/A$ is isomorphic to $D/C$, do you mean that the map induced by the inclusion $B\to D$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: yes, this is what I meant, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true, and is a consequence of the [Nine lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_lemma).

Consider the following commutative diagram:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
& & 0 && 0 && 0 \\
& & \da{} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  &  \\
0 & \ra{} & A & \ra{} & B & \ra{} & B/A & \ra{} & 0  \\
& & \da{} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  &  \\
0 & \ra{} & C & \ra{} & D & \ra{} & D/C & \ra{} & 0  \\
& & \da{} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  &  \\
0 & \ra{} & C/A & \ra{} & D/B & \ra{} & 0 & \ra{} & 0  \\
& & \da{} & & \da{} & & \da{} & &  &  \\
& & 0 && 0 && 0 \\
\end{array}
$$
The two left columns and two upper rows are exact by construction, and the right-most column is exact by your hypothesis.  By the nine lemma, the bottom row has to be exact.  Thus $C/A$ and $D/B$ are isomorphic.